# Customizing upload file functionality in SharePoint picture library

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

Can anyone help me ,I want to customize upload functionality in which i want to validate the uploaded image type  to the picture  library

where can i set my script ?? Any one can advise ???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might be Use [`ItemAdding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spitemeventreceiver.itemadding.aspx). In `ItemAdding` Event Method just check extension of the Document before successfully uploaded to the Library.if unvalid document than through Error message

your code something like this :

```
   protected string[] ValidExtensions = new string[] { "png", "jpeg", "gif"};

   public override void ItemAdding(SPItemEventProperties properties)
    {
        string strFileExtension = Path.GetExtension(properties.AfterUrl);

        bool isValidExtension = false;

        string strValidFileTypes = string.Empty;

        using (SPWeb web = properties.OpenWeb())
        {

                foreach (string strValidExt in ValidExtensions)
                {
                    if (strFileExtension.ToLower().EndsWith(strValidExt.ToLower()))
                    {
                        isValidExtension = true;
                    }
                    strValidFileTypes += (string.IsNullOrEmpty(strValidFileTypes) ? "" : ", ") + strValidExt;
                }

      // Here i am going to check is this validate or not if not than redirect to the 
      //Error Message Page. 
                if (!isValidExtension)
                {
                    properties.Status = SPEventReceiverStatus.CancelWithRedirectUrl;
                    properties.RedirectUrl = properties.WebUrl + "/_layouts/error.aspx?ErrorText=" + "Only " + strValidFileTypes + " extenstions are allowed";

                }

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use SPItemEventReceiver for your library and add your logic into ItemUpdating() and ItemAdding() methods.

Comment: Sorry ,but at item adding event receiver, the image still not uploaded yet ,will give me null exception

Comment: @qablan89, if I understand you correctly, you need to check extension exactly before uploading. So SPItemEventProperties object 'properties' which is parameter of ItemAdding() method contains properties BeforeUrl and AfterUrl. These properties contain name of file which user uploads.

Answer (score 0):

You can try creating a custom list template and replace the default `NewForm.aspx` and `EditForm.aspx` pages there. These [custom form templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa544142.aspx) need not contain the same user controls and buttons as in the default picture library template. You could create a Silverlight web part with rich UI to upload images, e.g. The more you want to differ the more code you'll have to write...

An OOTB solution I can think of would be a workflow that you would force every new picture to run through but it would be quite an overkill for the end-user...

Of course, if you're able to validate by using just the meta-data in [ItemAdding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spitemeventreceiver.itemadding.aspx) as the others suggest, it'd be a huge time-saver.

--- Ferda