# Check extension of choosing picture in SP 2013 Picture Library

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I need to check pictures extension when user has chosen picture and try to upload it into picture library.

I've found the way to edit master page with js script, but i haven't to edit master page. Then i try to use event receiver Adding, but it can't get the name of file or file path. I used:

```
var file = properties.ListItem.File.Name; //properties.ListItem - returns null
```

`AfterProperties` also returns null.

The another way i see is to edit Adding Picture form with js:[image: Adding picture form]

I think is's simplest way but i can't found information about it.

Problem: how to set js script to the form (see picture) or how to do such actions with another way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be realized with event receiver **ItemAdding** and with

> properties.AfterUrl

The same answered question with code in:

[Customizing upload file functionality in SharePoint picture library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10054319/customizing-upload-file-functionality-in-sharepoint-picture-library)

Answer (score -1):

In your case, a simple JS form validation will do. 
First I would prevent default action of the submit button.
Then, I would analyze the contents of the filename textbox and check the extention. If it's not one of the listed in the validation script, return false + alert "THis file extention is not supported".

Why would you want to use event receiver? It catches the event on server side.